# changing between the two word sentences, PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

in the text,  html codes to be found between **codeStart** and **codeEnd** words. This code is displayed as text and **pre** tag in between I want to be. preg_replace tried to do with it, but not like this :

```
function get_code($string)
{
  echo '<pre class="code"><p class="icon">'.
     preg_replace("/^codeStart (\w+) codeEnd$/m",
                    "htmlspecialchars('$1')",
                    $string).
    '</p></pre>';
}
```

A sample text is as follows:

> written an article for testing purposes. code is given below:

```
codeStart
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://example.com/images.png"></a>
codeEnd
```

> written for the more of testing text

Comment: First of all: `$string` is the entire text or only the 'codeStart(...)codeEnd' part?

Comment: $string : text I received from the database

Comment: codeStart and codeEnd : an ordinary word. To determine the start and end points

Comment: yes, but in your regex you have `/^codeStart` that means that 'codeStart' is at begin of the string. In **your example** above, `$string` start with 'written an article...' or with 'codeStart...'?

Comment: There is a text.when  I will add this code in the text,  between codeStart end codeEnd writing. And I want to show the text of this intermediate code.

Comment: I know this. but **in your example** above, what is the precise text that you pass to `getCode`? Is it 'written an article for testing purposes. code is given below:
codeStart
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://example.com/images.png"></a>
codeEnd
written for the more of testing text' **or** 'codeStart
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://example.com/images.png"></a>
codeEnd' **or** '<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://example.com/images.png"></a>'. I mean **The original text that you pass to function as argument ($string)**

Comment: So you just want to replace everything between the `codeStart` and `codeEnd` with something else?

Comment: yes exactly, @Quixrick

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 major problem in your `preg_replace` call.

First of all, what is the string that you pass to function?
In the provided example, it's seems to be that:

> written an article for testing purposes. code is given below:
>   codeStart
>   <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://example.com/images.png"></a>
>   codeEnd
>   written for the more of testing text

but in this case the pattern search fails because your pattern is `/^codeStart (\w+) codeEnd$/m`: you put a space after `codeStart` and another before `codeEnd`, but in your string this space exists? Or is a newline?

Second issue, the `(\w+)` subpattern: `\w` means «"word" characters» (letter, number, underscore): so, in example above, it's don't match spaces, `<`, `>`, etc...

Last but not least, you can't call a function like `htmlspecialchars` with `preg_replace`; you have to use `preg_replace_callback` with a user-defined function.

Your code will works in this way (tested):

```
function myCallback( $matches )
{
    return htmlspecialchars( $matches[1] );
}

function get_code( $string )
{
    echo '<pre class="code"><p class="icon">'.
    preg_replace_callback
    (
        "/^codeStart\W(.+)\WcodeEnd$/m",
        "myCallback",
        $string
    )
    .'</p></pre>';
}
```

In this example, I use `/^codeStart\W(.+)\WcodeEnd$/`, that means that the pattern match any occurrence of `codeStart` followed by **Non-word character** and then, in the first subpattern, **any character**; then, the user-defined function `myCallback` receive the matches of regular expression and apply `htmlspecialchars` at the first subpattern-match.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this seems pretty straightforward.  Basically all you'd need to do is match anything between `codeStart` and `codeEnd`.  You can use the `.*?` syntax to do that.  Something like this:

```
`codeStart(.*?)codeEnd`
```

So now, if we were to put that snippet into an actual script, it would look something like this:

```
// SET OUR DEFAULT STRING
$string = 'codeStart
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="http://example.com/images.png"></a>
codeEnd';

// DO THE PREG_REPLACE
$string = trim(htmlspecialchars(preg_replace("~codeStart(.*?)codeEnd~s", '$1', $string)));

print $string;
```

This will output:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.example.com&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://example.com/images.png&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thank both of you (@fusion3k and @quixrick). I got the results I wanted both of you to write that code combining separately.

```
"/^codeStart\W(.+)\WcodeEnd$/m",
```

instead of

```
"~codeStart(.*?)codeEnd~s",
```

type of work